# reactnative build failed when my project is 0.70.3

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**when i try to build my project it gives error**
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

`* Where:
Build file 'E:\BSAPharma\BSAPharma\android\app\build.gradle' line: 2
What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Could not find implementation class 'com.facebook.react.ReactPlugin' for plugin 'com.facebook.react' specified
>
> What went wrong:
> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>
> com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle`
>
> i tried delete and install node_modules and also deleted Home Users gradle folder and installed again **the version of project is**
> `"react": "18.2.0",     "react-native": "0.71.3",`
> **this is my build.gradle file**

```
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:7.3.1")
    }
}
```

Comment: Also put this file `E:\BSAPharma\BSAPharma\android\app\build.gradle` so that we can see what's happening.